# GUI not responding after child processes finishes due to redirection of Stdout

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing, stdout

I've spent the past few days reading various threads about making tkinter thread-safe and running children without blocking the main thread.  I thought I had arrived at a solution that allowed my code to run as I wanted it to, but now my main thread becomes non-responsive when my child process finishes.  I can move the window around but the GUI part shows a loading cursor, whites out, and says "Not Responding" in the title of the window.  I can let it sit like that forever and nothing will happen.  I know what part of the code is causing the problem but I am not sure why it's causing the GUI to freeze.  I'm using Windows.

I want my GUI to run another process using `multiprocess`.  I have `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` routed to a queue and I use `threading` to create a thread that holds an automatic queue checker that updates the GUI every 100 ms so my GUI updates in "real time".  I have tried every way of sending the child's `stdout/stderr` to the GUI and this is the only way that works the way I want it to (except for the freezing bit), so I would like to find out why it's freezing.  Or I would like help setting up a proper way of sending the child's output to the GUI.  I have tried every method I could find and I could not get them to work.

My main thread:

```
#### _______________IMPORT MODULES_________________###
import Tkinter
import multiprocessing
import sys
from threading import Thread
import qBMPchugger

###____________Widgets__________________###
class InputBox(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        # Styles
        self.grid()

        # Approval
        self.OKbutton = Tkinter.Button(self, text=u"OK", command=self.OKgo, anchor="e")
        self.OKbutton.pack(side="right")

        self.view = Tkinter.Text(self)
        self.view.pack(side="left")
        self.scroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.view.yview)
        self.view.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(side="left")

    def write(self, text):
        self.view.insert("end", text)

    def OKgo(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        sys.stderr = self

        checker = Thread(target=self._update)
        checker.daemon = True
        checker.start()

        self.view.delete(1.0, "end")
        self.update_idletasks()

        print("Loading user-specified inputs...")
        path = "C:/"
        inarg = (q, path)

        print("Creating the program environment and importing modules...")
        # Starts the text monitor to read output from the child process, BMPchugger
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=qBMPchugger.BMPcode, args=inarg)
        p.daemon = 1
        p.start()

    def _update(self):
        msg = q.get()
        self.write(msg)
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.after(100, self._update)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = InputBox(None)
    app.title("File Inputs and Program Settings")

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    app.mainloop()
```

My child process (qBMPchugger):

```
#### _______________INITIALIZE_________________###
import os
import sys
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

class BadInput(Exception):
    pass

def BMPcode(q, path):
    # Create root for message boxes
    boxRoot = Tkinter.Tk()
    boxRoot.withdraw()

    # Send outputs to the queue
    class output:
        def __init__(self, name, queue):
            self.name = name
            self.queue = queue

        def write(self, msg):
            self.queue.put(msg)

        def flush(self):
            sys.__stdout__.flush()

    class error:
        def __init__(self, name, queue):
            self.name = name
            self.queue = queue

        def write(self, msg):
            self.queue.put(msg)

        def flush(self):
            sys.__stderr__.flush()

    sys.stdout = output(sys.stdout, q)
    sys.stderr = error(sys.stderr, q)

    print("Checking out the Spatial Analyst extension from GIS...")
    # Check out extension and overwrite outputs

    ### _________________VERIFY INPUTS________________###
    print("Checking validity of specified inputs...")
    # Check that the provided file paths are valid
    inputs = path
    for i in inputs:
        if os.path.exists(i):
            pass
        else:
            message = "\nInvalid file path: {}\nCorrect the path name and try again.\n"
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Invalid Path", message.format(i))
            print message.format(i)
            raise BadInput
    print("Success!")
```

It's the part under `# Send outputs to the queue` (starting with the output class and ending with `sys.stderr = error(sys.stderr, q)`) that is causing my program to freeze.  Why is that holding up my main thread when the child process finishes executing?  **EDIT:  I think the freezing is being caused by the queue remaining open when the child process closes... or something.  It's not the particular snippet of code like I thought it was.  It happens even when I change the print statements to `q.put("text")` in either the parent or the child.**

What is a better way to send the output to the queue?  If you link me to a topic that answers my question, PLEASE show me how to implement it within my code.  I have not been successful with anything I've found so far and chances are that I've already tried that particular solution and failed.

Comment: Have you tried using `pdb` to step through the code and find out where it actually hangs?

Comment: No, I have not.  My skill level is too low to use a pdb effectively.

Comment: You have 2 Tk() instances which is never good. Pass the first/root instance to BMPcode and specify "parent=root_from_first_instance" for the tkMessageBox (options for it at effbot http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm )

Comment: How do I reference the parent inside of the child?  That's the reason I made a new root in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a manager list or dictionary to communicate between processes https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes . You can have a process update the dictionary and send it to the GUI/some code outside the processes, and vice versa.  The following is a simple, and a little sloppy, example of doing it both ways.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def test_f(test_d):
   """  frist process to run
        exit this process when dictionary's 'QUIT' == True
   """
   test_d['2'] = 2     ## add as a test
   while not test_d["QUIT"]:
      print "P1 test_f", test_d["QUIT"]
      test_d["ctr"] += 1
      time.sleep(1.0)

def test_f2(test_d):
    """ second process to run.  Runs until the for loop exits
   """
    for j in range(0, 10):
       ## print to show that changes made anywhere
       ## to the dictionary are seen by this process
       print "     P2", j, test_d
       time.sleep(0.5)

    print "second process finished"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ##--- create a dictionary via Manager
   manager = Manager()
   test_d = manager.dict()
   test_d["ctr"] = 0
   test_d["QUIT"] = False

   ##---  start first process and send dictionary
   p = Process(target=test_f, args=(test_d,))
   p.start()

   ##--- start second process
   p2 = Process(target=test_f2, args=(test_d,))
   p2.start()

   ##--- sleep 2 seconds and then change dictionary
   ##     to exit first process
   time.sleep(2.0)
   print "\nterminate first process"
   test_d["QUIT"] = True
   print "test_d changed"
   print "dictionary updated by processes", test_d

   ##---  may not be necessary, but I always terminate to be sure
   time.sleep(5.0)
   p.terminate()
   p2.terminate()
```

Comment: How do I add stdout to the dictionary?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer.  What is sent to stdout and how do you do it?  If it is just a string then assigning it to a dictionary key is simple.

Comment: Ah so reassign print statements so they're dict entries then.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

For my particular problem, the main thread was trying to read from the queue when the queue was empty and not having anything else put into it.  I don't know the exact details as to why the main loop got hung up on that thread (`self._update` in my code) but changing `_update` to the following stopped making the GUI non-responsive when the child finished:

```
def _update(self):
    if q.empty():
        pass
    else:
        msg = q.get()
        self.write(msg)
        self.update_idletasks()
```